# What is the number of perfect matchings on the one-dimensional skeleton of a $k$ dimensional cube?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, matching-theory

Let $Q_k$ denote the one skeleton of the $k$-dimensional cube. How many perfect matchings are there in $Q_k$?

I honestly don't even have a clue for this question. For $k=1$, there is trivially one, for $k=2$, there are two, for $k=3$, there are nine? Some people in my class have said that it should be $k^2$, but I have not seen any literature on this subject; [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph#Other_properties) only gives a lower bound for this. It seems like if there were an answer, it would be provided somewhere on the internet. A sketch of a proof or a link would be great. Thanks.

Edit: I do not have a sound definition of $Q_k$, nor even the $k$ dimensional cube. Even an answer providing definitions of those would be helpful.

Comment: How do you define the one dimensional skeleton of a hypercube ?

Comment: @JeanMarie how $\textit{do}$ you define it? My professor didn't give me a definition...

Comment: @JeanMarie i don't know how to work with objects that haven't been defined. thats also why i asked here. I would really appreciate it if you could refer me to some definitions or if you could write an answer which stated some of the definitions.

Comment: Looking at the Wikipedia article, I was completly surprized to see "a hypercube [...] is a closed, compact, convex figure whose **1-skeleton** consists of groups of opposite parallel line segments aligned in each of the space's dimensions, perpendicular to each other and of the same length." This is not what is called usually a skeleton in computional geometry ! Why don't they speak instead of the set of edges ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't know :(  it still doesn't really help me. how do you define it in terms of edges or vertices?

Comment: Besides, FYI: see [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Straight_skeleton_2/index.html) examples of what is usually meant by skeleton in computational geometry.

Comment: @JeanMarie the square, $Q_2$, isn't even complete.

Comment: You are right. I was wrong... Confusion with the simplex...

Comment: See [this reference](https://oeis.org/A005271/a005271.pdf)

Comment: see also: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11083-012-9279-8.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of complete matchings in the [hypercube graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) $Q_n$ is sequence [A005271](http://oeis.org/A005271) in [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org). It seems to be a hard problem; apparently the exact number is known only for $n\le7$:

> 1
> 2
> 9
> 272
> 589185
> 16332454526976
> 391689748492473664721077609089

Comment: See the reference I gave with a very interesting proof using permanents.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for pointing out the Graham–Harary paper, it looks very nice.